# IVR/SIP using Restcomm

Tags: sip, ivr, restcomm

I want to make my first IVR application. I searched the net and decided to use the Telestax. The problem now is that I can't find what to exactly use. Should I download both the Media Server and the SIP Servlets, and may be Jain-SIP?
My application will be a core application (not a web). Or I just need to download a library from the Restcomm libraries (as Restcomm-connect)?

I already tried to download the Restcomm-connect from the below link but couldn't find how to run the Olympus? Also no Media Server configuration found. Should I install everything separately and if yes, then how to connect them?
https://github.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Connect.

Again, my target is not a web application.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MON25 Restcomm-Connect is the right one to use. Do you run on Linux ?

Did you read the documentation at http://documentation.telestax.com/connect/index.html ?

If you want to start with Docker which is usually the most simple ay to get started , read http://documentation.telestax.com/connect/configuration/docker/Restcomm%20-%20Docker%20Quick%20Start%20Guide.html#restcomm-docker

If you want to run the binary read http://documentation.telestax.com/connect/configuration/Restcomm%20-%20Installing%20Restcomm%20from%20GitHub.html#restcomm-github-install

Comment: yes, I am using Centos 5 (some kind of old) on a virtual machine. I want to work with the connect binary but it seems doesn't include the SIP and Media Server as I indicated in my question. I installed it and when calling the "start-restcomm.sh" I see a lot of errors

Comment: Restcomm-Connect does include the SIP and Media Server. Please upload the logs at https://gist.github.com/ so we can see what's happening

Comment: I don't know exactly where to find the logs. I think that I am missing the introduction to the Restcomm!!!
Anyway, I uploaded the terminal output when calling the "start-restcomm.sh" and it is in the below link. Knowing that the "config-scripts" folder just has one subfolder named "as7-config-scripts".

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8524c1cde6dae5a5bdfc503c9a4b2ab6

Comment: Wait do you run start-restcomm.sh right out of the directory from a github clone command ?

Comment: You cannot run this script on the source code. please read http://documentation.telestax.com/connect/configuration/Restcomm%20-%20Installing%20Restcomm%20from%20GitHub.html#restcomm-github-install. If you really want to build it from source, read http://documentation.telestax.com/connect/configuration/How%20to%20build%20Restcomm-Connect%20from%20source.html#build-from-source

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that the Restcomm-Connect-master is a source version. I am installing now the "Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.8.0.962".
Thank you and see you in other questions :)